# How to solve C# Asynchronous Socket Programming Client/Server problem?

Tags: c#, sockets, asyncsocket

I found one article for this program . 
(https://www.gokhan-gokalp.com/en/c-ile-asenkron-socket-programlama/)

But I have problem it is not sending information Server to Client. 
I have to write receive method in client side and I have to right send method in server side. They are missing.
How can I implement ?

Client Side : Main program

```
using ExampleClient.Sockets;
using ExampleDataTransferObjects;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;

namespace ExampleClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int port = 5555;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Client Başlatıldı. Port: {0}", port));
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

            ExampleSocket exampleSocket = new ExampleSocket(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port));
            exampleSocket.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Göndermek için \"G\", basınız...");

            int count = 1;
            while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "G")
            {
                ExampleDTO exampleDTO = new ExampleDTO()
                {
                    Status = string.Format("{0}. Alındı", count),
                    Message = string.Format("{0} ip numaralı client üzerinden geliyorum!", GetLocalIPAddress())
                };

                exampleSocket.SendData(exampleDTO);
                count++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            string localIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(a => a.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

            return localIP;
        }
    }
}
```

Client.cs: This client will pass data to server.

```
using ExampleDataTransferObjects;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ExampleClient.Sockets
{
    public class ExampleSocket
    {
        #region Variables
        Socket _Socket;
        IPEndPoint _IPEndPoint;

        // Socket işlemleri sırasında oluşabilecek errorları bu enum ile handle edebiliriz.
        SocketError socketError;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[1024];
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public ExampleSocket(IPEndPoint ipEndPoint)
        {
            _IPEndPoint = ipEndPoint;

            // Socket'i tanımlıyoruz IPv4, socket tipimiz stream olacak ve TCP Protokolü ile haberleşeceğiz. 
            // TCP Protokolünde server belirlenen portu dinler ve gelen istekleri karşılar oysaki UDP Protokolünde tek bir socket üzerinden birden çok client'a ulaşmak mümkündür.
            _Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public void Start()
        {
            // BeginConnect ile asenkron olarak bir bağlantı başlatıyoruz.
            _Socket.BeginConnect(_IPEndPoint, OnBeginConnect, null);
        }

        public void SendData(ExampleDTO exampleDTO)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // İlgili object'imizi binary'e serialize ediyoruz.
                new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, exampleDTO);
                IList<ArraySegment<byte>> data = new List<ArraySegment<byte>>();

                data.Add(new ArraySegment<byte>(ms.ToArray()));

                // Gönderme işlemine başlıyoruz.
                _Socket.BeginSend(data, SocketFlags.None, out socketError, (asyncResult) =>
                {
                    // Gönderme işlemini bitiriyoruz.
                    int length = _Socket.EndSend(asyncResult, out socketError);

                    if (length <= 0 || socketError != SocketError.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Server bağlantısı koptu!");
                        return;
                    }
                }, null);

                if (socketError != SocketError.Success)
                    Console.WriteLine("Server bağlantısı koptu!");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        void OnBeginConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                // Bağlanma işlemini bitiriyoruz.
                _Socket.EndConnect(asyncResult);

                // Bağlandığımız socket üzerinden datayı dinlemeye başlıyoruz.
                _Socket.BeginReceive(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnBeginReceive, null);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                // Servera bağlanamama durumlarında bize SocketException fırlatıcaktır. Hataları burada handle edebilirsiniz.
                Console.WriteLine("Servera bağlanılamıyor!");
            }
        }

        void OnBeginReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            // Almayı bitiriyoruz ve geriye gelen byte array'in boyutunu vermektedir.
            int receivedDataLength = _Socket.EndReceive(asyncResult, out socketError);

            if (receivedDataLength <= 0 || socketError != SocketError.Success)
            {
                // Gelen byte array verisi boş ise bağlantı kopmuş demektir. Burayı istediğiniz gibi handle edebilirsiniz.
                Console.WriteLine("Server bağlantısı koptu!");
                return;
            }

            // Tekrardan socket üzerinden datayı dinlemeye başlıyoruz.
            _Socket.BeginReceive(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnBeginReceive, null);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

ExampleDataTransferObjects.dll: this dll will transfer data client to server

```
using System;

namespace ExampleDataTransferObjects
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize edebilmek için Serializable attributü ile işaretliyoruz.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class ExampleDTO
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Server Side:

Client.cs: It will receive data and send to listener

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ExampleServer.Sockets
{
    public delegate void OnExampleDTOReceived(ExampleDTO eDTO);

    public class Client
    {
        #region Variables
        public OnExampleDTOReceived _OnExampleDTOReceived;
        Socket _Socket;

        // Socket işlemleri sırasında oluşabilecek errorları bu enum ile handle edebiliriz.
        SocketError socketError;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[1024]; // 1024 boyutunda temp bir buffer, gelen verinin boyutu kadarıyla bunu receive kısmında handle edeceğiz.
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public Client(Socket socket)
        {
            _Socket = socket;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public void Start()
        {
            // Socket üzerinden data dinlemeye başlıyoruz.
            _Socket.BeginReceive(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnBeginReceiveCallback, null);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        void OnBeginReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            // Almayı bitiriyoruz ve gelen byte array'in boyutunu vermektedir.
            int receivedDataLength = _Socket.EndReceive(asyncResult, out socketError);

            if (receivedDataLength <= 0 && socketError != SocketError.Success)
            {
                // Gelen byte array verisi boş ise bağlantı kopmuş demektir. Burayı istediğiniz gibi handle edebilirsiniz.
                return;
            }

            // Gelen byte array boyutunda yeni bir byte array oluşturuyoruz.
            byte[] resizedBuffer = new byte[receivedDataLength];

            Array.Copy(tempBuffer, 0, resizedBuffer, 0, resizedBuffer.Length);

            // Gelen datayı burada ele alacağız.
            HandleReceivedData(resizedBuffer);

            // Tekrardan socket üzerinden data dinlemeye başlıyoruz.
            // Start();

            // Socket üzerinden data dinlemeye başlıyoruz.
            _Socket.BeginReceive(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnBeginReceiveCallback, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gelen datayı handle edeceğimiz nokta.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resizedBuffer"></param>
        void HandleReceivedData(byte[] resizedBuffer)
        {
            if (_OnExampleDTOReceived != null)
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(resizedBuffer))
                {
                    // BinaryFormatter aracılığı ile object tipimize geri deserialize işlemi gerçekleştiriyoruz ve ilgili delegate'e parametre olarak geçiyoruz.
                    ExampleDTO exampleDTO = new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms) as ExampleDTO;

                    _OnExampleDTOReceived(exampleDTO);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Listener: it will listen data async

```
using ExampleDataTransferObjects;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ExampleServer.Sockets
{
    public class Listener
    {
        #region Variables
        Socket _Socket;
        int _Port;
        int _MaxConnectionQueue;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public Listener(int port, int maxConnectionQueue)
        {
            _Port = port;
            _MaxConnectionQueue = maxConnectionQueue;

            // Socket'i tanımlıyoruz IPv4, socket tipimiz stream olacak ve TCP Protokolü ile haberleşeceğiz. 
            // TCP Protokolünde server belirlenen portu dinler ve gelen istekleri karşılar oysaki UDP Protokolünde tek bir socket üzerinden birden çok client'a ulaşmak mümkündür.
            _Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public void Start()
        {
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _Port);

            // Socket'e herhangi bir yerden ve belirttiğimiz porttan gelecek olan bağlantıları belirtmeliyiz.
            _Socket.Bind(ipEndPoint);

            // Socketten gelecek olan bağlantıları dinlemeye başlıyoruz ve maksimum dinleyeceği bağlantıyı belirtiyoruz.
            _Socket.Listen(_MaxConnectionQueue);

            // BeginAccept ile asenkron olarak gelen bağlantıları kabul ediyoruz.
            _Socket.BeginAccept(OnBeginAccept, _Socket);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        void OnBeginAccept(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            Socket socket = _Socket.EndAccept(asyncResult);
            Client client = new Client(socket);

            // Client tarafından gönderilen datamızı işleyeceğimiz kısım.
            client._OnExampleDTOReceived += new Sockets.OnExampleDTOReceived(OnExampleDTOReceived);
            client.Start();

            // Tekrardan dinlemeye devam diyoruz.
            _Socket.BeginAccept(OnBeginAccept, null);
        }

        void OnExampleDTOReceived(ExampleDTO exampleDTO)
        {
            // Client tarafından gelen data, istediğiniz gibi burada handle edebilirsiniz senaryonuza göre.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Status: {0}", exampleDTO.Status));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message: {0}", exampleDTO.Message));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Server Main Program:

```
using ExampleServer.Sockets;
using System;

namespace ExampleServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int port = 5555;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server Başlatıldı. Port: {0}", port));
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

            Listener listener = new Listener(port, 50);

            listener.Start();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I have problem it is not sending information Server to Client. How can I implement?"_ -- what have you tried? Sending data to the client is exactly like sending data to the server, except with the roles reversed. All the same calls you are already using are used; you just put the "send" part in the server, and the "receive" part in the client. What is it you _specifically_ need help with here? Please improve the question. See also [ask] for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: hi @PeterDuniho yes exactly you understood my problem . I dont have receive method on client side also I dont have send method in server side. I dont know how can I implement this part

Comment: You _do_ have a receive method on the server side, and a send method on the client side. So, there's your example right there. Just implement each same basic idea in the other, respectively.

Comment: I think you just need to have different port. Client listen at 5555 then server send message at 5555. While server listen at 5556 and client send to 5556. If you use the same port, your client/server could be consuming the message the client sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem in client.cs with this code :

```
 void HandleReceivedData(byte[] resizedBuffer)
        {
            if (_OnExampleDTOReceived != null)
            {
                //using (var ms = new MemoryStream(resizedBuffer))
                //{
                //    // BinaryFormatter aracılığı ile object tipimize geri deserialize işlemi gerçekleştiriyoruz ve ilgili delegate'e parametre olarak geçiyoruz.
                //    string exampleDTO = new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms) as string;

                //    if (exampleDTO == "POSALIVE")
                //        SendData("ACK");

                //    _OnExampleDTOReceived(exampleDTO);
                //}

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(resizedBuffer))
                {
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                    string myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    if (myStr.Contains("POSALIVE"))
                        SendData("ACK");
                    _OnExampleDTOReceived(myStr);
                }
            }
        }

        public void SendData(string message)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // İlgili object'imizi binary'e serialize ediyoruz.
                new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, message);
                IList<ArraySegment<byte>> data = new List<ArraySegment<byte>>();

                data.Add(new ArraySegment<byte>(ms.ToArray()));

                // Gönderme işlemine başlıyoruz.
                _Socket.BeginSend(data, SocketFlags.None, out socketError, (asyncResult) =>
                {
                    // Gönderme işlemini bitiriyoruz.
                    int length = _Socket.EndSend(asyncResult, out socketError);

                    if (length <= 0 || socketError != SocketError.Success)
                    {
                        log.append("Server bağlantısı koptu!", "");
                        return;
                    }
                }, null);

                if (socketError != SocketError.Success)
                    log.append("Server bağlantısı koptu!", "");
            }
        }
```

I added sent data method in client.cs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you signalR for full duplex communication between client and server.
https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Also, I modified your code for ServerToClient communication, you can find it below.

In ExampleSocket.cs, define two new variables

```
    #region Variables
    Socket _Socket;
    IPEndPoint _IPEndPoint;
    //new
    SocketError socketError;
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[1024];
    //new
    #endregion
```

In ExampleSocket.cs, add below line to your Start() function

```
  public void Start()
    {
        // BeginConnect ile asenkron olarak bir bağlantı başlatıyoruz.
        _Socket.BeginConnect(_IPEndPoint, OnBeginConnect, null);
        //new 
        _Socket.BeginReceive(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnBeginReceiveCallback, null);
        //new
    }
```

In ExampleSocket.cs, add new function like below

```
    //new
    void OnBeginReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        int receivedDataLength = _Socket.EndReceive(asyncResult, out socketError);

        if (receivedDataLength <= 0 && socketError != SocketError.Success)
            return;


        byte[] resizedBuffer = new byte[receivedDataLength];

        Array.Copy(tempBuffer, 0, resizedBuffer, 0, resizedBuffer.Length);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(resizedBuffer))
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            string myStr = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("From server : {0}", myStr));
        }
        _Socket.BeginReceive(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnBeginReceiveCallback, null);
    }
    //new
```

In Listener.cs, add new function like below

```
   //new
    public void Send(string s)
    {
        client.Send(s);
    }
    //new
```

In Client.cs, add new function like below

```
     //new
    public void Send(string s)
    {

        if (_Socket.Connected)
        {
            Byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s.ToCharArray());
            _Socket.Send(byteData, byteData.Length, 0);
        }

    }
    //new
```

In ExampleServer.Program, modify your Main(string[] args) function

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int port = 5555;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server Başlatıldı. Port: {0}", port));
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

        Listener listener = new Listener(port, 50);

        listener.Start();

        //new
        bool dewamke = true;

        while (dewamke)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write exit to close or write anything for sending data.");
            var cmd = Console.ReadLine();
            if (cmd == "exit")
                dewamke = false;
            else
                listener.Send(cmd);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("closing server.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        //new
    }
```